# Detect a rough image on screen

Tags: screen, shapes, detection, contrast

I'm scrolling through CT scans of bone and I'd like to detect when a general shape occurs on screen.  I'll be going through many different subjects, and no two will be exactly alike - however, they will have very similarly shaped bones.  Is there a way to input a general shape to detect, though not a precise one?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Could you post your code through editing this question? Please show us what you tried to do. `Thank you very much :)`

Comment: To be honest with you, I have a very limited background with coding!  I haven't tried anything here yet because I don't even know where to start.  I'm sure there are some libraries that facilitate edge detection with images on-screen.  If you could point me in the right direction, I'd be happy to tinker with it and get back to you for specifics :)